# Unable to clone BitBucket repository in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, bitbucket

my problem is when I try to clone an existing repository from BitBucket Visual Studio asks me for user authentication. Actually asks me twice. Once I type my login and password (I am an admin user on my comuter) it asks me again. Then it says

> An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2.
>   Category = Net (Error). Response status code does not indicate
>   success: 401 (Unauthorized).

I tried also with the user and password from BitBucket - same result.

I am not signed up for Visual Studio Team Services in Visual Studio, is it possible this is causing my problem?

My Visual Studio:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.21005.1 REL
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When connecting to BitBucket you should use the password you've set for the service. But at the moment I have issues connecting with Visual Studio 2015 as well.

Comment: Not being connected to Visual Studio Team Service or TFS should not make any difference.

Comment: I try since yesterday (20 hours ago) - when I decided to start using repository.

Comment: can't connect with GitKraken either. Looks like a bug in LibGit2 or in BitBucket. I pinged @BitBucket on twitter and forwarded this post to the people maintaining Git inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you tried again? I still can't connect to the repository.

Comment: @jessehouwing have you tried again? I still can't connect. Is it still BitBucket or me this time?

Comment: Still not working for me either. I can get the git commandline to work, but nothing that uses LibGit2 or a derivative. Looks like it's known, but an incorrect thing on the BitBucket side: https://twitter.com/ethomson/status/723956033362792448